# R add loess line to subset of data in scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, line

I am trying to fit separate loess lines to two sets of data in scatterplot that are distinguished by a factor. My data

```
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c('type1', 'type2'), 12, replace = T), var2=sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE), var3 =c(rnorm(12)))
```

Scatterplot my two groups of datapoints separately:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(4,4,0.5,0.5), mgp = c(1.5, 0.3, 0), tck = -0.01)
plot(var3 ~ var2, data=mydf[mydf$var1=="type1",], xlim = c(0, 12), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "x axis", ylab = "y axis", pch = 21, col = "red")
points(var3 ~ var2, data=mydf[mydf$var1=="type2",], xlim = c(0, 12), ylim = c(-2, 2), xlab = "x axis", ylab = "y axis", pch = 21, col = "slateblue")
```

Now the problem. Not sure how to tell R to use only the points with var1 = type2

```
#?
loess_fit <- loess(var3 ~ var2, data=mydf[mydf$var1=="type2",])
lines(mydf$var2, predict(loess_fit), col = "blue")
```

Comment: any reason this won't work? `lines(mydf[mydf$var1 == "type2", "var2"], predict(loess_fit), col = "blue")`

Comment: Does this really mimic your data well? I keep getting warnings about mathematical pathology in the fitting process. The warnings go away if the numbers are increased but the discrete nature of the var2 variable makes the  defatult loess fit rather bizarre.

Comment: I could not make  lines(mydf[mydf$var1 == "type2", "var2"], predict(loess_fit), col = "blue") work for me the way I need it to - a separate line with different color for the two sets of points. I just get 3 straight blue lines. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The loess may not work well with these data, but I was just making a simple example for the post. The real data are more extensive. Is there a better fitting procedure?

Comment: Better fitting procedure for data with  .... what features? Numbers of points? Does the "X" variable have the wide gaps that your example has? Will you need to adjust the bandwidth to get a less pathological result?

Comment: Have you attempted `lines(mydf$var2, loess_fit$fitted, col = "blue")` ?